# How to process sound in Java for Android?

Tags: android

Folks,

As a start, I would like to develop a Java application that will act as a guitar tuner. The application should listen to what I play on the guitar and tell me the notes I played. I am wondering what level of support is provided by Android SDK. Do I need any other open source library? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Peter

Comment: As for how to get the audio into a file, this should get you started: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#capture